# Serverless Framework how to create an AWS SQS DeadLetter queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

I am trying to create an AWS SQS Dead Letter Queue, using the serverless framework
The idea is to have a SQS to trigger a Lambda function,
and have another SQS as a DeadLetterQueue, ie. to pick up the message in case the Lambda fails or timesout

I did the following to create a test project -

```
mkdir dlq
cd dlq/
serverless create --template aws-nodejs
```

**Following is my serverless.yaml -**

```
service: dlq

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: ap-southeast-1
  role: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/dlqLambdaRole

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-lambda-dead-letter

functions:
  dlq:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - MainQueue
              - Arn

    deadLetter:
      targetArn:
        GetResourceArn: DeadLetterQueue

resources:
    Resources:  
        MainQueue:
            Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
            Properties:
                QueueName: main
        DeadLetterQueue:
            Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
            Properties:
                QueueName: dlq
```

**I also tried the following -**

```
service: dlq

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: ap-southeast-1
  role: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/dlqLambdaRole

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-lambda-dead-letter

functions:
  dlq:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - MainQueue
              - Arn

    deadLetter:
      sqs: dlq

resources:
    Resources:
      MainQueue:
        Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
        Properties:
          QueueName: main
```

But in both these cases, the framework is just creating a normal SQS

I am following this document -
https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-lambda-dead-letter

Answer (score -5, accepted):

To give you some background, Dead Letter Queue is just that, a normal SQS queue. it's the configuration at AWS Lambda that informs it to push message to this Queue whenever there is any error while processing the message.

You can verify this from the management console by referring to the "Dead-letter queue service" under "Asynchronous invocation"

[image]

Comment: I understand but, how can I configure to be a DLQ using serverless framework ? I don’t want to manually edit my main queue and add the dlq to it

Comment: Your primary queue i.e. the one that triggers lambda cannot be the DLQ, This will create a race condition where an error puts a message back into a queue that again triggers lambda producing the same error. You will have to create a new queue and use that as the DLQ.

Comment: @Ani, if the answer did indeed address your question, do you mind accepting it. That way, others who stumble upon this can easily find the solution. Cheers.

Comment: the message is staying in flight in the main queue, and throwing error on the function, the message isn't going to the dlq

Answer (score 15):

Better late than never. Hope this helps you or someone searching for this problem.

When you configure SQS to trigger Lambda, the DLQ is supposed to be configured on the SQS(Since it would not be an Asynchronous invocation).
Notice the 'Note' section in the link
[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-queueconfig)

Hence your serverless.yaml needs to declare the ReddrivePolicy in the main queue to refer to the DLQ. (Below)

```
service: dlq

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: ap-southeast-1
  role: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/dlqLambdaRole


functions:
  dlq:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - MainQueue
              - Arn

    deadLetter:
      targetArn:
        GetResourceArn: DeadLetterQueue

resources:
    Resources:  
        MainQueue:
            Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
            Properties:
                QueueName: main
                RedrivePolicy: 
                  deadLetterTargetArn: 
                    Fn::GetAtt: 
                      - "DeadLetterQueue"
                      - "Arn"
                  maxReceiveCount: 5
        DeadLetterQueue:
            Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
            Properties:
                QueueName: dlq
```

maxReceiveCount is set to 5 as per AWS Documentation.

Comment: Why do you have a 'deadLetter' section in functions? Are you using the serverless-plugin-lambda-dead-letter plugin?

Comment: Definitely better late than never, thank you!